# an answer of a test data is different from my answer on my code

Tags: c, fractions, mixed

Here is the problem,  http://judgegirl.csie.org/problem/0/202.

When I scan a test data:

```
-2
1
3
3
-1
3
7
```

The answer is:

```
1
19
30
```

But my answer on my code is:

```
1
-19
30
```

Moreover, I add the condition of the absolute value, but in vain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
int gcd(int,int);
main ()
{
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h, i,j,x,y,z,GCD,abs;
        scanf ("%d\n", &a); 
        scanf ("%d\n", &b); 
        scanf ("%d\n", &c); 
        scanf ("%d\n", &d); 
        scanf ("%d\n", &e); 
        scanf ("%d\n", &f); 
        scanf ("%d\n", &g); 
        if ((a != 0 )&&(e!=0)&&(a>=-100)&&(a<=100)&&(e>=-100)&&(e<=100)&&(b>=0)&&(f>=0)&&(b<=100)&&(f<=100)&&(c>0)&&(g>0)&&(c<=100)&&(g<=100)){
            switch ( d ){
                case 0 :
                    if (a>0 && e>0){
                        x = a + e +(b*g + f*c)/(c*g); 
                        y = (b*g + f*c)%(c*g);
                        z = c*g ;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a>0 && e<0){
                        x = a + e +(b*g - f*c)/(c*g);
                        y = (b*g - f*c)%(c*g);
                        z = c*g ;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a<0 && e>0){
                        x = a + e +((-b)*g + f*c )/(c*g);
                        y = ((-b)*g + f*c)%(c*g);
                        z = c*g ;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a<0 && e<0){
                        x = a + e +((-b)*g - f*c)/(c*g);
                        y = ((-b)*g - f*c)%(c*g);
                        z = c*g ;
                        break ;
                    }
                case 1 :
                    if (a>0 && e>0){
                        x = a - e + (b*g - f*c)/(c*g);
                        y = (b*g - f*c)% (c*g);
                        z = c*g;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a>0 && e<0){
                        x = a - e+(b*g + f*c)/(c*g) ;
                        y = (b*g + f*c )%(c*g);
                        z = c*g ;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a<0 && e>0){
                        x = a - e+((-b*g )- f*c)/(c*g) ;
                        y = ((-b)*g - f*c)%(c*g) ;
                        z = c*g ;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a<0 && e<0){
                        x = a - e +((-b)*g + f*c)/(c*g) ;
                        y = ((-b)*g + f*c )%(c*g);
                        z = c*g ;
                        break ;
                    }
                case 2 :
                    if (a>0 && e>0){
                        x = (c*a + b)*(e*g + f)/(c*g);
                        y = (c*a + b)*(e*g + f)%(c*g);
                        z = c*g;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a>0 && e<0){
                        x = (c*a + b)*(e*g - f)/(c*g);
                        y = (c*a + b)*(e*g - f)%(c*g);
                        z = c*g;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a<0 && e>0){
                        x = (c*a - b)*(e*g + f)/(c*g);
                        y = (c*a - b)*(e*g + f)%(c*g);
                        z = c*g;
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a<0 && e<0){
                        x = (c*a - b)*(e*g - f)/(c*g);
                        y = (c*a - b)*(e*g - f)%(c*g);
                        z = c*g;
                        break ;
                    }
                case 3 :
                    if (a>0 && e>0){
                        x = ((c*a+b)*g)/(c*(e*g+f));
                        y = ((c*a+b)*g)%(c*(e*g+f));
                        z = c*(e*g+f);
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a>0 && e<0){
                        x = ((c*a+b)*g)/(c*(e*g-f));
                        y = ((c*a+b)*g)%(c*(e*g-f));
                        z = c*(e*g-f);
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a<0 && e>0){
                        x = ((c*a-b)*g)/(c*(e*g+f));
                        y = ((c*a-b)*g)%(c*(e*g+f));
                        z = c*(e*g+f);
                        break ;
                    }
                    if (a<0 && e<0){
                        x = ((c*a-b)*g)/(c*(e*g-f));
                        y = ((c*a-b)*g)%(c*(e*g-f));
                        z = c*(e*g-f);
                        break ;
                    }
        } 

        if (y>0){
            abs = y;
        }
        else {
            abs = -y;
        }
        GCD=gcd(abs,z);
        abs = abs/GCD;
        z = z/GCD;
        printf ("%d\n",x);
        printf ("%d\n",abs);
        printf ("%d\n",z);
        }
    }
    int gcd(int abs , int z)
    {
        if (!z) return (abs); 
        return gcd(z, abs % z);
    }
```

Comment: Generally, before posting a "find my error" question, you will want to narrow down where your error is and why you can't solve it. You can begin by including `printf` statements to look at intermediate values or by using a general debugger like `gdb` to glean the same information from  your running code. If you wrote the code, then you are more than competent to determine where the values go south.

Comment: the if and else of abs y seems to be a doubtfull case. try changing the condition, if u believe that absolute value can solve your issue. Also your abs is not initialized and it is possible there could be an already existing negative garbage value which may have triggered only y being un-obidient and rest two values to be output fine.....